# MDX Expression : Calculated Member

Tags: mdx, olap-cube, powerpivot, tableau-api

I am trying to create a **Calculated Member** on a Microsoft Analysis Services Cube.

There is an existing Dimension  `[Projects][Project Number - Name]` which has members along the line of "12345 - Project X". I need to extract the project number only ("12345").

I initially assumed it would be as simple as `LEFT(Projects].[Project Number - Name],5)`, but this yields a `null` response.

Even if i just repeat the dimension as is `[Projects].[Project Number - Name]`, I get a `null`.

I've tried `[Projects].[Project Number - Name].Value, [Projects].[Project Number - Name].Members` and a host of other ideas, but I am (as you can probably see) shooting in the dark.

I am primarily trying to get this working in Tableau (*needs an MDX expression, not full query*), but have also tried the Calculated Member functionality in MS Excel Power Pivot, which yields exactly the same answer (`null`) - which suggests that my MDX is questionable.

Comment: See if this helps:   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1739116-ecff-4357-b0c6-29f387831c1c/how-to-get-a-left-function-in-mdx-language?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Comment: thanks this did get me going in the right direction. I now have `LEFT([Projects].[Project Number - Name].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME,5) working, but only if I also include the original [Projects].[Project Number - Name] dimension included elsewhere in the worksheet. If I take the orgional dimension out the calculated member goes to null... ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try :

```
LEFT( [Projects].[Project Number - Name].currentMember.name, 5 )
```

Otherwise, [Projects].[Project Number - Name] references a member which then is converted to a tuple and then evaluated. So your expression is actually processing the result of this tuple evaluation and not the name of the member itself.

Comment: This returns the Dimension Name  ("Project Number - Name") rather than the Member value ("12345 Project X") .... ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the .currentMember call - is that ok now?